# Python: Nested list comprehensions using deep copies

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to create something like this:

```
lst = [[None, None], [None, None], [None, None]]
```

using list comprehensions.  However, whatever I try, I find that performing `lst[0][0] = True` does not have the desired effect.  Instead of making the list `lst = [[True, None], [None, None], [None, None]]`, it changes it to `lst = [[True, None], [True, None], [True, None]]`.

Here's the different ways that I've tried creating my list comprehension:

```
lst = [[None] * 2] * 3
lst = [copy.deepcopy([None] * 2)] * 3
lst = [list([None] * 2])[::]] * 3
```

Comment: You realize that you  are **NOT** using list comprehensions. Otherwise you would not encounter this issue ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Those are not comprehensions, check this proper comprehension example:

```py
lst = [[None for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(3)]
```

Here you have a comprehensive [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list) for your problem.

Comment: `[[None] * 2 for _ in range(3)]` would also work.

Comment: @Guy, yes it would, but better not to mix those since he seems not to know how things really work.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use:

```
l = [[None,None] for i in range(3)]
l[0][0]=True
print(l)
>>> [[True, None], [None, None], [None, None]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're having is due to the way you created your list.

As @Zanga showed, creating the list using list comprehension will not have the same behavior as the way you created it when doing `lst[0][0] =True`.

Because in the way you created the list ( `lst = [[None] * 2] * 3` ), you created a list ( `[None, None]` ) that you duplicated three time. Then, when trying to modify the first element of the first list, it modifies the first element of all list because there are all duplicates (stored in the same memory location).